# Swift - Firebase - order collection

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve some documents but I need them to be ordered by some data ("ListIDX") inside my "Wishlists" - `collection`.

I tried this but that's not allowed:

`db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").order(by: "ListIDX").document(list.name).collection("wünsche").getDocuments()`

This is my `function`:

```
    func getWishes (){
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

            var counter = 0

            for list in self.dataSourceArray {
print(list.name) // -> right order
                db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").document(list.name).collection("wünsche").getDocuments() { ( querySnapshot, error) in
print(list.name) // wrong order
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }else{
                        // DMAG - create a new Wish array
                        var wList: [Wish] = [Wish]()
                        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                            let documentData = document.data()
                            let wishName = documentData["name"]
                            wList.append(Wish(withWishName: wishName as! String, checked: false))
                        }
                        // DMAG - set the array of wishes to the userWishListData
                        self.dataSourceArray[counter].wishData = wList
                        counter += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is what I actually would like to achieve in the end:

```
self.dataSourceArray[ListIDX].wishData = wList
```

***Update***

I also have a function that retrieves my `wishlists` in the right order. Maybe I can add `getWishes`in there so it is in the right order as well.

```
    func retrieveUserDataFromDB() -> Void {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").order(by: "listIDX").getDocuments() { ( querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }else {
                // get all documents from "wishlists"-collection and save attributes
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let documentData = document.data()
                    let listName = documentData["name"]
                    let listImageIDX = documentData["imageIDX"]

                    // if-case for Main Wishlist
                    if listImageIDX as? Int == nil {
                        self.dataSourceArray.append(Wishlist(name: listName as! String, image: UIImage(named: "iconRoundedImage")!, wishData: [Wish]()))
                        // set the drop down menu's options
                        self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownOptions.append(listName as! String)
                        self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownListImages.append(UIImage(named: "iconRoundedImage")!)
                    }else {

                        self.dataSourceArray.append(Wishlist(name: listName as! String, image: self.images[listImageIDX as! Int], wishData: [Wish]()))

                        self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownOptions.append(listName as! String)
                        self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownListImages.append(self.images[listImageIDX as! Int])
                    }

//                    // create an empty wishlist
//                    wList = [Wish]()
//                    self.userWishListData.append(wList)

                    // reload collectionView and tableView
                    self.theCollectionView.reloadData()
                    self.dropDownButton.dropView.tableView.reloadData()

                }

            }
            self.getWishes()
        }
```

***For a better understanding:***

[git repo](https://github.com/chriskonnerth/Wishlist)

Comment: Looking at your proposed code: collection("wishlists").order(by: "ListIDX").document(list.name) - you may have multiple documents in your "wishlists" collection, but you are fetching only one that has the id = list.name. So it doesn't make any sense to order those documents. That's why it's not supported. You probably should explain better what's your data structure and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @alrgrid I need to insert wList at the right index in sourceDataArray. That is my problem. Retrieving wünsche if list.name is ordered would be exactly the right order. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly. It's spreads out the information across multiple posts. Help us to help you by keeping focus on one question at a time. As mentioned in the comments of the other two questions, Firestore is asynchronous and data may be returned from different nodes at different times. The only guarantee is if the data is ordered in the query - for example your `listIDX` data will be ordered by that. The solution is to simply order the `self.dataSourceArray` by whatever property you want once all of the data has been retrieved.

Comment: The other option, if you want to add additional info to the dataSource array is to look up the index of the list object in that array, then add the additional data to it. Something like this pseudo code `let index = self.dataSourceArray.firstIndex(of: list)` and then use that index to update the object at that index.

Answer (score 1):

As @algrid says, there is no sense to order the `collection` using `order()` if you are going to get an specific element using `list.name` at the end, not the first or the last. I would suggest to change your code to:

```
db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").document(list.name).collection("wünsche").getDocuments()
```

Comment: I need to insert `wList` at the right index in `sourceDataArray`.  That is my problem. Retrieving `wünsche` if  `list.name` is ordered would be exactly the right order. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to retrieve some documents but I need them to be ordered by some data ("ListIDX")

The following line of code will definitely help you achieve that:

```
db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").order(by: "ListIDX").getDocuments() {/* ... */}
```

Adding another `.document(list.name)` call after `.order(by: "ListIDX")` is not allowed because this function returns a Firestore `Query` object and there is no way you can chain such a function since it does not exist in that class.

Furthermore, Firestore queries are shallow, meaning that they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from a top-level collection and a sub-collection in a single query. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections in one go. A single query may only use the properties of documents in a single collection. So the most simple solution I can think of would be to use two different queries and merge the results client-side. The first one would be the above query which returns a list of "wishlists" and the second one would be a query that can help you get all wishes that exist within each `wishlist` object in `wünsche` subcollection.

Comment: I was thinking about that but I don't really know how to do that as I am still quite new to Firestore. Could you maybe elaborate ? :) I also have a `function` where I retrieve my `wishlists`, will update my question

Comment: To achieve that you need to use nested queries. So the second query that will help you get all wishes that exist within each `wishlist` should be placed inside the first callback, that's it.

Comment: I saw your edited question. The solution is in my above comment. Have you tried it?

Comment: I did try some things but nothing worked. I just realized that it might be some other reason after all because my `dataSourceArray` is ordered and my `for-loop` goes though that ordered list so it should be right but it's not and I have no idea why... I will update my question again with my git.

Comment: after I retrieve the `wishlists` in the second function I posted in my question, `dataSourceArray` is ordered just fine. However I just printed `dataSourceArray` in my `getWishes` function and in there it is not in the right order anymore...

Comment: I updated my `getWishes` in my question so you can see my `print` tests

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I added another attribute when saving a `wish` that tracks the index of the list it is being added to. Maybe not the smoothest way but it works. Thanks for all the help :)