# Firestore query multiple documents with for loop

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query multiple documents using a `for-loop`.

My database set up looks like this:

users -> wishlists -> all the users Wishlists(containing different Wishlists with `name`) -> wünsche

The items are getting retrieved but in the wrong order. I tried couple of different things but nothing worked so far.

```
func getWishes() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    var counter = 0

    for list in self.dataSourceArray {
        print(list.name) // -> right order
    }

    for list in self.dataSourceArray {
         db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").document(list.name).collection("wünsche").getDocuments() { ( querySnapshot, error) in
            print(list.name) // -> wrong order

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                // create new Wish array
                var wList: [Wish] = [Wish]()
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let documentData = document.data()
                    let wishName = documentData["name"]
                    wList.append(Wish(withWishName: wishName as! String, checked: false))
                }

                self.dataSourceArray[counter].wishData = wList
                counter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this function inside another function that  retrieves all the `wishlist` in the right order:

```
func getWishlists() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").order(by: "listIDX").getDocuments() { ( querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }else {
            // get all documents from "wishlists"-collection and save attributes
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let documentData = document.data()
                let listName = documentData["name"]
                let listImageIDX = documentData["imageIDX"]

                // if-case for Main Wishlist
                if listImageIDX as? Int == nil {
                    self.dataSourceArray.append(Wishlist(name: listName as! String, image: UIImage(named: "iconRoundedImage")!, wishData: [Wish]()))
                    // set the drop down menu's options
                    self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownOptions.append(listName as! String)
                    self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownListImages.append(UIImage(named: "iconRoundedImage")!)
                }else {

                    self.dataSourceArray.append(Wishlist(name: listName as! String, image: self.images[listImageIDX as! Int], wishData: [Wish]()))

                    self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownOptions.append(listName as! String)
                    self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownListImages.append(self.images[listImageIDX as! Int])
                }

                // reload collectionView and tableView
                self.theCollectionView.reloadData()
                self.dropDownButton.dropView.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
        self.theCollectionView.isHidden = false
        self.getWishes()
    }
}
```

***DataSourceArray in the right order: *** Main Wishlist, Goals, boost

***Output from 2nd `print`-test:*** boost, Goals, Main Wishlist

Comment: if the append works as expected here `self.dataSourceArray[counter].wishData = wList` why you care for order or it doesn't

Comment: This question doesn't look much different than the first time you posted it.  Could you edit the question to show the exact data you're working with, and illustrate clearly what the "right order" is, how that compares to what you're getting that's not the way you want?

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the question. I hope that helps

Comment: It's not clear to me at all why you're modifying `self.dataSourceArray` inside loop of the same array.  That seems like a bad idea. Could you explain what in English what you're trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: ok let me try to explain it. Think of my app as a simple to-do-app. Inside the app the user can create different projects and inside the projects the user can add tasks. In my case projects are "Wishlists" that have an image and a name and tasks are "Wünsche" that have a name. Does that clarify things?

Comment: @DougStevenson in `retrieveWishlist I get all the Wishlists with their name and image and append them to `dataSourceArray` . Since Firestore doesn't really order items each Wishlist has a "ListIDX" which I use to order it in the right way. So after `retrieveWishlists` , `dataSourceArray` contains the Wishlists ( with their image and name) in the right order but without the Wishes. With `getWishes` i want to "fill"  `wishData` which holds all the wishes of each Wishlist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - Firebase - order collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556505/swift-firebase-order-collection)

Comment: This is the third time you've asked the same question. Please stick to the original question as asking the same question repeatedly spreads out the information.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though you are trying to make a bunch of API calls at once and it is returning values at different times. You could attempt to make your calls synchronously to maintain order or you could try to use dispatch groups like the pseudo code below:

```
let myGroup = DispatchGroup()

struct DataItem {
    let order: Int
    let data: DataYouWantToSave
}

var fetchedData = [DataItem]()

for i in list {
    myGroup.enter()

    let dataItem = DataItem()
    dataItem.order = i

    db.collection...
        print("Finished request \(i)")
        dataItem.data = DataYouWantToSave
        fetchedData.apped(dataItem)
        myGroup.leave()
    }
}

myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("Finished all requests.")
    // Reorder your array of data items here.
    let sortedArray = fetchedData.sorted(by: { $0.order > $1.order })

    // If you just want the array of data values
    let newData: [DataYouWantToSave] = sortedArray.map { $0.data }
}
```